# Connection: keep-alive in nginx webserver

Tags: nginx

I have enabled the Connection: keep-alive in my nginx webserver. And its working fine as well. My query is in nginx access logs i am getting the below message many times. I believe its due to the keep-alive but what exactly the server is doing? Thanks in advance.

Access Log Message:
"GET / HTTP/1.0" 302 43 "-" "HTTP-Monitor/1.1" "-"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, when the keep alive activates the web server sends a packet to the client to indicate that the connection is still active, so those messages are in the log.

Sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-)

Comment: If that is case why 302 redirection is happening? i feel whatever the http/1.0 request is coming to server is redirected to http/1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Is that nginx behind some load balancer? If it is, it's a health check from it.